# How to change dataframe's name flexibly?

Tags: python, pandas

I have many dataframes with names like this data_v1,data,v2,data_v3,data_v11,data_v12 etc.

Now I like to loop over each dataframe and apply a function to each of dataframe. So I need to provide dataframe name. since the name is the same in the first part. 2nd part after_ is different. So how to write dataframe name in the way like below? below has an error which says data_ is not defined. Thank you so much for your help

```
variable=['v1','v2','v3','v11','v12','v13']
for var in variable:
    function(data_%s %var)
```

Comment: 'data_v1,data,v2,data_v3,data_v11,data_v12' is that supposed to be 'data_v1,data_v2,data_v3,data_v11,data_v12'?

Comment: Yes, Scott. How to correct show code format? which shortcut do I use to display the code correct? Thanks

Comment: The better question is how you created the dataframes. This probably should have been done by creating a `dict` of dataframes, where the names of the dataframes are `keys`.

Comment: I think it is about how to use string of object name to represent the object itself, can i just use eval(string)?

Comment: `df_list = [eval(var) for var in dir() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)]`

Comment: Definitely agree with Trenton, I can't see how a solution such as you describe could be preferable to creating a proper collection of dataframes when they were generated in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [A.B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3680831/a-b) provided

  - `[var for var in dir() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)]`

    - This creates a list of dataframe names as strings
  - `isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)` finds any `DataFrame` in the current instance.

```py
import pandas as pd

# creates a list of strings
df_names_str = [var for var in dir() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)]

# creates a list of dataframes
df_list = [eval(var) for var in dir() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)]

# creates a dict of dataframes
df_dict = {f'{var}': eval(var) for var in dir() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)}

# test function
def test(v: pd.DataFrame):
    print(v.info())


# function call with list of dataframes
for var in df_list:
    test(var)

# function call with dict of dataframes
for k, v in df_dict.items():
    test(v)
```

### Using your loop

- The string name must be evaluated to convert it to a pandas dataframe object.

```py
variable=['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v11', 'v12', 'v13']

for var in variables:
    function(eval(f'data_{var}'))
```

Answer (score 0):

basic solution:

```
 variable=['v1','v2','v3','v11','v12','v13']
    for var in variable:
    function("data_"+var)
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, inspired all of your help, I think the best solution is using dictionary to save dataframe's name as key of the dictionary.

```
    for var in ['v1','v2','v3','v11','v12','v13']:
        function(data_dict['data_'+var.lower()])
```